# How to use CanConvert() of reflect.Value

Tags: go

I have a `reflect.Value` type of data and I want to check if the value can be convert to `uint` or not.

this is just an example hope you guys get the idea

```
var myVal = new(reflect.Value)
if myVal.CanConvert(uint) { // this doesn't work
   // do stuf...
}
```

I dont know what I have to pass as the argument of CanConvert()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to the [CanConvert method](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.CanConvert) is a [reflect.Type](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Type).  Use the [reflect.TypeOf](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#TypeOf) function to get a reflect.Type from a value of the type.

```
if myVal.CanConvert(reflect.TypeOf(uint(0)) { 
   // do stuff...
}
```